# unable to navigate to the updated URL in URL Maintenance in PEOPLESOFT

Tags: peoplesoft

I have hyperlink properties as static external link . so when updating for URL, I have changed URLID in URL maintenance under below navigation.

```
peopletools-->administration-->utilities-->URL's
```

These changes have been migrated from one instance to another. but after navigating to the particular location , its not letting me to the updated page. instead its navigating me to the old page.  I was wondering what would be the reason?

Comment: to add, this change is not happening in Manager Self Service page

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another language installed? If so, the URL table have a lang record, you should check at the Lang record.
Which tools are u?